# no matching function in C++: constant tag added to calling function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am just starting my adventure in the land of C++, so this may be a silly question. I am getting the following error from my compiler.

Run.cc:56: error: no matching function for call to ‘sphereDetect::getArrayPtr() const’
/spheredetect.hh:18: note: candidates are: const G4long (* sphereDetect::getArrayPtr())[36][72][60]

**my Run.hh is:**

```
#include "spheredetect.hh"
#include "G4Run.hh"
#include "globals.hh"

class G4Event;

/// Run class
///

class Run : public G4Run
{
  public:
    Run();
    virtual ~Run();

    // method from the base class
    virtual void Merge(const G4Run*);

    void AddEdep (G4double edep);

    // get methods
    G4double GetEdep()  const { return fEdep; }
    G4double GetEdep2() const { return fEdep2; }

  private:
    G4double  fEdep;
    G4double  fEdep2;
    sphereDetect scatter;
};
```

**my Run.cc is:**

```
#include "Run.hh"

//....oooOO0OOooo........oooOO0OOooo........oooOO0OOooo........oooOO0OOooo......

Run::Run()
: G4Run(),
  fEdep(0.),
  fEdep2(0.),
  scatter()
{}

//....oooOO0OOooo........oooOO0OOooo........oooOO0OOooo........oooOO0OOooo......

Run::~Run()
{}

//....oooOO0OOooo........oooOO0OOooo........oooOO0OOooo........oooOO0OOooo......

void Run::Merge(const G4Run* run)
{


  const Run* localRun = static_cast<const Run*>(run);
  fEdep  += localRun->fEdep;
  fEdep2 += localRun->fEdep2;
  arr* scatterPointer = localRun->scatter.getArrayPtr();
  scatter.sphereMerge(scatterPointer);
  G4Run::Merge(run);
}

//....oooOO0OOooo........oooOO0OOooo........oooOO0OOooo........oooOO0OOooo......

void Run::AddEdep (G4double edep)
{
  fEdep  += edep;
  fEdep2 += edep*edep;
}
```

**and my sphereDetect.hh is:**

```
typedef G4long arr[36][72][60];
class sphereDetect
{
public:
    sphereDetect();
     ~sphereDetect();
      const arr* getArrayPtr() {return &scatterArray;}
     void sphereMerge(arr*);
     void createHit(G4ThreeVector,G4double);
protected:
     void storeHit(G4int,G4int,G4int);
     G4int findAngNS(G4ThreeVector);
     G4int findAngEW(G4ThreeVector);
     G4int findEnergy(G4double);

     void sphereSave();

private:


    G4long scatterArray[36][72][60];

};
```

I am fairly lost as to how to resolve this. Is it in the way i construct or call the sphereDetect class? The one thing that is certain is that the input for the Run.Merge is required to be that input(based on the previous code).

Any help is greatly appreciated,

- Will

Comment: `const arr* getArrayPtr() {}` should be `const arr* getArrayPtr() const {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're short a `const`.

```
 const arr* getArrayPtr() {}
```

Means "this returns a const pointer".

```
 const arr* getArrayPtr() const {}
```

Means "this returns a const pointer, and can be called on a const object". Otherwise, the compiler can't tell that `getArrayPtr()` doesn't want to modify the object on which it's called.

Since `localRun` is `const`, it's member `localRun->scatter` is `const`, too.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is looking for a definition of `getArrayPtr()` which declares that it will not modify the object and thus is safe to call on a `const` object. This is done by putting the `const` after the rest of the function signature, just like `G4double GetEdep()  const` has it.